# Easy recolor map, fewest colors, preserving adjacency (Python)?

Tags: python, colors, openstreetmap

[image]

TL;DR: Python library to recolor the above so adjacent colors remain different

I have an image representing a polygonal Voronoi map of the 50 states, which, when overlaid on OpenStreetMaps at 50% transparency, looks something like the above. The original image is large (32768x32768) and available at https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ONEOFF/statesv2-merc.png for reference.

There are 50 separate colors in the image, but some of the colors, for example California and Arizona, are visually close to each other, especially at 50% (and lower) transparency

I want to recolor the image with the fewest number of colors so that no two colors that are adjacent in the original image have the same color. This is almost identical to the 5-color problem (and thus to a few other Stack questions), but, because some states consist of multiple noncontiguous polygons, a little different. In other words, it's possible for one color in the original image to be adjacent to an arbitrary number of colors.

I'm almost sure that this requires an intermediate step of creating a color adjacency for the image. I found [How to recolor image based on edge detection(canny)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936103/how-to-recolor-image-based-on-edge-detectioncanny) which is similar but different and an R library that might do this, https://github.com/hunzikp/MapColoring but nothing for Python

I'm pretty sure I could do this myself, but prefer a tested library.